# Given that $T(-1,2,-1) = (-7,-3)$, $T(0,-1,1) = (4,3)$ and $T(-2,3,0) = (-7,-3)$, determine $T(-4,8,-1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\textbf{R}^{3}\to\textbf{R}^{2}$ be a linear transformation. Given that $T(-1,2,-1) = (-7,-3)$, $T(0,-1,1) = (4,3)$ and $T(-2,3,0) = (-7,-3)$, determine $T(-4,8,-1)$.

(a) $(−42,−18)$

(b) $(−7,−3)$

(c) $(10,3)$

(d) $(−29,−15)$

(e) $(−19,−12)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: Protip: when you ask a question here, the system will give a list of related questions.  (Under "Related" at the right hand side of the window - you should also have been shown these when you were composing your question.)  In the current list I can see two that should tell you pretty much exactly what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find the real numbers $a,b,c$ such that: $(-4,8,-1) = a(-1,2,-1)+b(0,-1,1)+c(-2,3,0)\implies \begin{cases} -a-2c = -4 \\ 2a-b+3c = 8 \\ -a+b = -1 \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} -a - 2c = -4 \\ a + 3c = 7\end{cases}\implies c = 3, a = -2, b = -3\implies T(-4,8,-1) = 3T(-1,2,-1)-3T(0,-1,1)-2T(-2,3,0)=3(-7,-3)-3(4,3)-2(-7,-3)=(-19,-12) \implies \text{e)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome.